# Swift: FileManager cannot resolve specific files

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I stored all of my audio files (names contain UTF-8 cyrillic chars) under a directory. Everything worked fine in a simulator, all files were resolving, FileManager's method `fileExists(atPath:)` returned all true.
But when I started the application on my iPhone, it could not resolve certain songs:

[image]

And I have this problem with 20% of my audio files. If I rename them (using only English letters), they will start resolving. I believe that there is a problem with character encoding, however rest of the songs are resolving correctly (which also contain UTF-8 cyrillic chars). I think it is Apple bug.

Here is the screenshot (same exact input) from the emulator:
[image]

Have anyone had this problem before?
If you need more info, feel free to comment under my post. I'll respond immediately.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post an example of a file name that works in the sim and doesn't work on the phone, and an example of a file that works on both? NB: the simulator file system is not case sensitive, but the phone is. Be careful with that

Comment: Use the `fileExists` with `filter` to get a list of all of the failing path names to help determine the common factor.

Comment: Also check that those spaces are actually spaces (0x20 or 32 decimal) and not some other fancy character.

Comment: Just a wild suggestion: try  Base64 encode the file name before storing and decode on reading back from storage. Base64.encodeToString(byte[], Base64.NO_WRAP); then byte[] result = Base64.decode(byte[], Base64.NO_WRAP); coming back from storage.

Comment: Sorry! I tried to edit, but it was too late. Just came from an Android post and thought this was an Android issue. But, you could still do the Base64 encoding and decoding